# Adding animation to image change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, animation

I have been trying to implement changing images onclick in React. I have 3 images stacked on top of each-other and what I am doing is changing the src attribute of images. Despite the functionality itself working properly, I couldn't manage to add transition animation. I was trying to get smth similar to what is on the photo

[stack of photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdNoQ.png)

I ran into some solutions based on the fact that animation is only played once when the component is rendered for the first time, and to cause re-render of image elements, I had to assign 'key' attribute to images, however it didn't work for me. However, I might be getting smth wrong.

I would be grateful for any kind of assistance:)

Here are the parts of code concerned:

```
const [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState(1);



const nextImg = () => {
activeImage === 5 ? setActiveImage(1) : setActiveImage(activeImage+1)
}

const prevImg = () => {
activeImage === 1 ? setActiveImage(5) :setActiveImage(activeImage-1)
}


<div className="frame">
        <img key={activeImage} className="current-image" src={`/src/assets/images/${activeImage}.jpg`} />            
        <img key={activeImage + 1} className="next-image" src={`/src/assets/images/${activeImage === 5 ? activeImage-4 : activeImage + 1}.jpg`} />
        <img key={activeImage + 2} className="next-2-image" src={`/src/assets/images/${activeImage === 4 || activeImage === 5 ? activeImage-3 : activeImage + 2}.jpg`} />
    </div>`

      <button className='left' onClick={prevImg}><Arrow /></button>
      <button className='right' id='right' onClick={nextImg}><Arrow /></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use image like that,
you should import first, example code like:

```
import A from './img/pictureA.png'
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={A} alt='I am A' width={'200px'}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So, You can change your code like this (Just remember to change picture number).

```
import pic1 from '../src/assets/images/1.jpg'
import pic2 from '../src/assets/images/2.jpg'
import pic3 from '../src/assets/images/3.jpg'

<div className='frame'>
                    <img
                        key={activeImage}
                        className='current-image'
                        src={pic1}
                        alt=''
                    />
                    <img
                        alt=''
                        key={activeImage + 1}
                        className='next-image'
                        src={`${activeImage === 5 ? pic1 : pic2}`}
                    />
                    <img
                        alt=''
                        key={activeImage + 2}
                        className='next-2-image'
                        src={`${
                            activeImage === 4 || activeImage === 5 ? pic3 : pic1
                        }`}
                    />
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't figured out why yet, but it really seemed to make the transition work